# Get indices and values of an ndarray in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a ndarray `A` of arbitrary number of dimensions `N`. I want to create an array `B` of tuples (array, or lists) where the first `N` elements in each tuple are the index and the last element is the value of that index in `A`.

For example:

```
A = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Then

```
B = [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```

What is best/fastest way to do this in NumPy without `for` loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Python 3 a very simple (and moderately fast) way would be (using [`np.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> [(*idx, val) for idx, val in np.ndenumerate(A)]
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```

It would be a bit different if you want it to work for both Python 3 and Python 2, because Python 2 doesn't allow iterable unpacking inside a tuple literal. But you could use tuple concatenation (addition):

```
>>> [idx + (val,) for idx, val in np.ndenumerate(A)]
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```

---

If you want to completely stay within NumPy it would be better to create the indices with [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
>>> grid = np.mgrid[:A.shape[0], :A.shape[1]]  # indices!
>>> np.stack([grid[0], grid[1], A]).reshape(3, -1).T
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 2, 6]])
```

However that would require a loop to convert it to a list of tuples... But it would be easy to convert it to a list of list:

```
>>> np.stack([grid[0], grid[1], A]).reshape(3, -1).T.tolist()
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 4], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 6]]
```

The list of tuples is also possible without *visible* `for`-loop:

```
>>> list(map(tuple, np.stack([grid[0], grid[1], A]).reshape(3, -1).T.tolist()))
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```

Even though there is no visible `for`-loop the `tolist`, `list`, `tuple` and the `map` do hide a `for`-loop in the Python layer.

---

For arbitary dimensional arrays you need to change the latter approach a bit:

```
coords = tuple(map(slice, A.shape))
grid = np.mgrid[coords]

# array version
np.stack(list(grid) + [A]).reshape(A.ndim+1, -1).T
# list of list version
np.stack(list(grid) + [A]).reshape(A.ndim+1, -1).T.tolist()
# list of tuple version
list(map(tuple, np.stack(list(grid) + [A]).reshape(A.ndim+1, -1).T.tolist()))
```

The `ndenumerate` approach would work for arrays of any dimensions without change and according to my timings only be 2-3 times slower.

Comment: You've just added to my knowledge bank

Comment: @MSeifert thanks, but I am looking for something without a for-loop. Because these matrices will potentially be huge, and Python's for-loop is pretty slow. Do you think that's possible? (p.s. only Python3 needs to work)

Comment: @SiaRezaei Not if you want a list of tuples. If an array would be okay then have a look at the second part (the `mgrid` approach) of my answer.

Comment: @SiaRezaei Yes, it's possible without `for`-loop. But be careful. I don't think any of both approaches will be "fast".

Comment: @MSeifert thanks, how should I change that code so it works with an A with any number of dimensions?

Comment: Use the `ndenumerate` approach if you're dealing with arbitrary dimensional arrays. That will be (at most) 2-3 times slower and works for any number of dimensions. And it's actually very clean code and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `np.ndindex`, although @Mseifert's approach is pretty unbeatable on timing and brevity.  The only loop here is to zip up the generator of coordinates with the actual values.  (Same as in the other answer.)

```
def tuple_index(a):
    indices = np.ndindex(*a.shape)
    return [(*i, j) for i, j in zip(indices, a.flatten())]

print(tuple_index(a))
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```