# Efficient way to convert numpy matrix into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy2d array that is a symmetric matrix (square matrix where the numbers above the diagonal are the same as the number below the diagonal)

Example input matrix:

```
edgeMatrix = np.array([[0., 2., 9.],
                       [2., 0., 1.],
                       [9., 1., 0.]])
```

I am looking for a very efficient way to convert this large matrix into a nested dictionary where the first key is the row index of the matrix and the second dict key is the column index of the matrix. ex:

Desired resulting nested dict format:

```
edgeDict[0][0] = 0
edgeDict[0][1] = 2
edgeDict[0][2] = 9
edgeDict[1][0] = 2
edgeDict[1][1] = 0
edgeDict[1][2] = 1
edgeDict[2][0] = 9
edgeDict[2][1] = 1
edgeDict[2][2] = 0
```

I have tried using `dict(enumerate(edgeMatrix.flatten(), 1))`, but failed to figure out how to get the nested aspect of this working.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want a `dict` of `dict`? A list of lists would have the same usage syntax (for reading data/setting existing elements) but would be faster to allocate, smaller in memory footprint and faster in lookup performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get indices and values of an ndarray in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107169/get-indices-and-values-of-an-ndarray-in-numpy)

Comment: The reason i need a dict and not a list is that this feeds into a package parameter that requires a dict, not a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your nested dict using a nested generator expression.

```
import numpy as np

edgeMatrix = np.array(
    [[0., 2., 9.],
    [2., 0., 1.],
    [9., 1., 0.]]
)

edgeDict = dict(enumerate(dict(enumerate(row)) for row in edgeMatrix))
print(edgeDict)
```

**output**

```
{0: {0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 9.0}, 1: {0: 2.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 1.0}, 2: {0: 9.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0}}
```

Comment: This is running in 1.37s

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [5]: {i: {j: edgeMatrix[i,j] for (j, _) in enumerate(edgeMatrix[i])} 
for (i, __) in enumerate(edgeMatrix)}

Out[5]: 
{0: {0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 9.0},
 1: {0: 2.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 1.0},
 2: {0: 9.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0}}
```

Comment: So far this is the fastest method.  I clocked it at 0.046s!  Validating the result and then will accept answer if the numbers are correct.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake with input data - this is running 2.4 sec

Answer (score 0):

`pandas`  does it for you :

```
In [38]: pd.DataFrame(a).to_dict()
Out[38]: 
{0: {0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 9.0},
 1: {0: 2.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 1.0},
 2: {0: 9.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0}}
```

Comment: Works and runs in 1.88s